# Undefined getSelection in textAngular

Tags: angularjs, textangular

When i am clicking text area then i got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined" and while typing "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSelection' of undefined".

I am using requirejs with angular. 
My config given below:

```
paths: {
        jquery     : '../lib/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
        angular    : '../lib/bower_components/angular/angular.min',
        ngCookies  : '../lib/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min',
        ngResource : '../lib/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min',
        ngRoute    : '../lib/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min',
        ngSanitize : '../lib/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min',
        textRangy : '../lib/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-rangy.min',
        textAngular : '../lib/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min',
        textAngularSetup : '../lib/bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngularSetup',
}
```

and dependencies

```
textAngular: { deps: ['angular', 'textRangy']}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

For more please look the attached file.